# Difficulty Registering/using VB .Net DLL for use in VBA/Com Interop

Tags: vb.net, vba, dll, com-interop

I have created a library I want to be able to share with colleagues, containing functions they can access from the VBIDE within MSOffice applications. I am using Visual Studio Express 2010, so I haven't been able to get the IDE to automatically register the DLL - instead, I have used RegAsm.exe. After several hours of desperate Googling, I finally managed to get the DLL (TLB) to appear in the VBIDE references menu. Whilst I have lots of classes in the DLL, I only exposed one as a ComClass:

```
<ComClass(RandomDemographicData.ClassId, RandomDemographicData.InterfaceId, RandomDemographicData.EventsId)> Public Class RandomDemographicData
    Public Const ClassId As String = "05DC232D-D584-4739-8DDE-6FCA997EDC0C"
    Public Const InterfaceId As String = "8FBD540B-3884-4585-9C90-47E42666FB63"
    Public Const EventsId As String = "736CDFDC-D240-4DC7-9BE6-9167054221ED"


    Public Function aName() As String

        Return "Hello World"

    End Function

End Class
```

Then I called it in VBA with:

```
Sub fgjhfh()

Dim f As New RandomDemographicData

Debug.Print f.aName

End Sub
```

But I get error "'-2147024894 (80070002)': Automation Error: system cannot find the file specified". I seem tantalizingly close to my goal, but can't quite make it - is anyone able to help?

EDIT:

The RegAsm command I used was "RegAsm.exe MyVBALib.dll /tlb:MyVBALib.tlb /codebase  following advice found in the last post [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/654801-dll-entry-point-error.html). I have also made a copy of RegAsm.exe in the folder containing the DLL

Comment: You are not using Regasm.exe correctly.  Random guessing is required since you did not specify how you used it.  A common mistake is forgetting the /codebase option.

Comment: Hi Hans, Thanks for your feedback. Please see my edit to the post.

Comment: Then a dependent assembly would be the next random guess.  Use SysInternals' Process Monitor.  You'll see the program searching for the file and not finding it.

Comment: OK, so I would appreciate any help you can give on using ProcMon - I think I can see the process with an issue, but don't know how to interpret it: 16:20:19.3201193 EXCEL.EXE 9480 RegOpenKey HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\Roaming NAME NOT FOUND Desired Access: Maximum Allowed

Comment: Well, that's not it, you are looking for an attempt at opening a file that failed.  Start from the bottom of the trace.  Do expect to spend at least several hours to learn how to utility works if you never used it before.  Effective filtering can be important to not drown in the data.  Ask questions about it at superuser.com

Comment: Ok, Thanks Hans. Will do.

Comment: here is guide that helped me: http://richnewman.wordpress.com/2007/04/15/a-beginner%E2%80%99s-guide-to-calling-a-net-library-from-excel/

Comment: Second thing: Did you use right version of RegAsm - 32/64-bit?

Comment: I have now managed to sort it out - it seems like the classes in the library that were not exposed to COM were causing the issue. I went through the DLL, adding the ComClass tag to all the classes that would support it, and it now works correctly. The only strange thing is that when I use a VBA public function to create a worksheet formula which uses a Random() in the DLL, the Worksheet_Change event doesn't seem to cause all the cells with that function to generate new content. You have to actually edit the cell and then exit it before the value refreshes. Different question though.